# How to connect to Redshift via Dbeaver using Active Directory users securely?

Tags: amazon-redshift, adfs

I want to connect to Redshift via Dbeaver using Active directory users and their credentials securely using ADFS.
In my case, I have my Redshift cluster deployed in one account and want to connect through JDBC URL to SQL clients (for e.g Dbeaver).

What roles and policies do I have to attach to my cluster to be accessible from the AD users created via ADFS.

Can you plz help me with this query?

Comment: Hi!
This should be a starting point for your investigation.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/generating-iam-credentials-steps.html